# filtering ON checkboxes in DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, filter, datatables

is there a simple way to filter based on a value of a checkbox in a DataTable? Everything I've searched just shows me how to use checkboxes to specify filters. not what i need. I want to type in true in the footer searchbox (or the likes) and it limit my datatable to lines that have true for that checkbox value.

i think that makes sense, thanks in advance for anyone's time solving this :D

here's a partial of the partial where the checkbox is, for clarification;

```
<tr>
     //...blah blah blah, other <td>'s

     <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ApprovedPoints)</td>
     <td>@Model.Notes @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Notes)</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Approved)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer with the info you're giving me.

As far i know (i could be wrong)  the datatable have not "checkboxes" your control does (datagrid for example).

If you're displaying a checkbox, the type in your dataTable might be boolean.

So, if you want to get the rows with that data in "true" you could apply a select (is a method of a datatable)

```
 result as datarow() = myDatatable.select("mycolumn = value")  'this method returns an array of datarows  where you can iterate through.
```

If you want to show the result in a control, you might to use

```
 myDatatable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "mycolumn = value"
 myDataGrid.dataBind 'if Im not wrong this is applied when you apply a databind to the control
```

There are plenty of information about both methods in the web, you can google from here.

Or if you expect a more precise answer please add more information.
What language are you working with?, what kind of tecnology?  you're working with a desktop application? or a asp webpage? or another crazy thing ¬¬ . what controls are you using?, what tou want to do with the result?

A little piece of the code where you want to implement the solution could help with all of the above.

Comment: it's an asp webpage, long story short, i want the option to find and only view unchecked lines. 

i added the partial above for some clarification, i'm trying to filter on the Approved value, just like i can filter on ApprovedPoints or Notes with a <th> in the footer of a DataTable.